# Is get-stellar (dot) org a Stellar scam site?

Tags: discussion

It sends you a memo with the http link, then it asks you to redeem stellar with a link landing you to a copycat of stellar account-viewer webpage.

Is that site really a scam?

[edit: typos]

Comment: Yes, it's clearly a scam. Stellar Development Foundation does not use transaction `memo` field for broadcasting notifications. Trust only emails received from `@stellar.org` address, official website https://stellar.org, and the official Twitter account [@StellarOrg](https://twitter.com/StellarOrg).